# Fingerprint tree generation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

There is group of people [let's say 1874 of them], all representing different companies [lets say 236 of them] in the world. My task is to best identify what company each person works for. The trick is that I cannot simply ask a person "Where do you work for" and get the answer, but what I do have is a questionnaire with a number of question [lets say 290 questions] and the exact responses I should expect for employees of each company. Some companies might have identical answers, so at the end, even if I can not determine exactly what company a person works for, I should be able to narrow it down and say that he/she must work for one of these companies.

Using multi-value maps, and some other data structures, I've gone as far as determining all the companies that I can identify with 1 question [query]. Using these queries to represent the root of a tree data-structure, I need to build out the rest of the tree using other queries/questions as branches to identify the rest.

Any advice/help/suggestion ?

Comment: Unless each company has only one pattern of answers that maps to it (though multiple companies attached to a single pattern is okay), I don't think a tree would be the most space-efficient data type to use. There's also the problem of how the tree might end up being Unless each company has only one pattern of answers that maps to it (though multiple companies attached to a single pattern is okay), I don't think a tree would be the most space-efficient data type to use. You could also have inefficiency if the tree ends up being unbalanced.

Comment: @JAB yes, each company has a single pattern of answers that match to it, and yes, a couple of companies will share thesame exact pattern. Space efficiency and balanced tree are not important [nor is tree generation time, so even a O(n!) won't be the end of the world] because in the end, the tree won't ever exceed a 1000 nodes [hell even 200 will be seriously pushing it].

Comment: Are all employees going to always answer the same way?  How many questions do you get to ask each employee?  If the answers are "yes" and "all", then you can just use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie to efficiently store all of the combinations of expected answers and at the root, the company or companies that would give those answers.  If one of them is "no", then more work is needed.

Comment: @btilly yes, employees will answer the same way. I would not say "all", but something more along the lines of "as many as you need to". Thanks for the link, checking it out

Comment: btilly: Do you mean at the leaves? Because storing all the company data at the root node would be pointless as it's the traversal to the leaves that specifies which company (or companies) are valid.

Comment: @JAB I did mean at the leaves.  About the questions.  Are they asked interactively, or not?  As in do you get to decide what question to ask next based on previous responses, or do you hand out a fixed piece of paper and they answer the questions regardless of what they said before?

Comment: Also are these yes/no questions, or multiple choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer in the comments, I feel that you may as well just have each level of your tree represent a question, and the branches/subnodes of the nodes on that level representing the answers. This would technically be a trie, as mentioned by btilly.

A more efficient (though not necessarily space-wise) solution would possibly involve using a hashtable and a hash function that acts on the answer choices to create its hash, but I think a trie is the best way to go given your requirements and the don't-cares.

Oh, right: depending on how the answer choices are laid out, it's possible you may have a series of answers on particular branches where there aren't any sub-branches/trees for a few levels; in such a case, you could potentially collapse those singular branch sections into individual nodes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries might also provide some tips.

---

Based on your response to my initial answer, here's my idea:

Keep an array of nodes for the questions and their answer choices, with each answer choice being associated with a hash table (or whatever data structure you'd wish to use; I suggested a hash table due to using Python a lot and being used to Python's `set` data structure, which is implemented as a type of hash table) containing pointers to each company, or a pointer to a single company if a given answer for a given question will indicate the company to begin with.

The first time you check an answer to a specific question, and there are multiple companies associated with that answer choice, make a temporary copy of the data in that first answer's hash table as a linked list or something. As more questions are answered, check the elements of the list against the hash table of each new answer, and remove companies that are not present in each new answer's hash table from the list. Repeat the question-asking process until 1) only one company is left in the list, 2) no companies are left in the list, or 3) you've asked all the questions.

If 1), that is the question-answerer's employer.
If 2), the employee isn't employed by any of the companies to check for, and/or there's an error somewhere.
If 3), the companies remaining in the linked list are the possible companies that question-answerer is employed by.

There's probably a more efficient method of doing this, as my implementation would require a minimum of 580 hash tables (one for each answer, with a minimum of 2 answers per question), but I can't really think of anything right now.

Comment: I started with something like that, and I succeeded at creating the top level of nodes. So I can ask a question and figure out based on the answer whether I have a match on the exact company or multiple matches on the company. If I have multiple matches, I'm a bit stuck trying to figure out how to generate the next levels. Maybe reading the Trie wiki page will help, I feel like I need some kind of recursive algorithm to generate the rest of the tree right ?

Comment: Ah, you aren't asking the questions in order. That makes things a bit more difficult, and means a hashtable as I described would definitely not be the right way to go. I'll see what I can think of...

Comment: Anyway, added my new idea to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Build the tree recursively, starting at the root.  At each step, you'll have an active set of questionnaires, which initially will be all of the questionnaires.  From the active questionnaires, select a question that has about as many yes answers as no answers.  Make a tree node for this question.  Create a yes subtree (recursively), using the subset questionnaires that answered yes for the question you selected at this node.  Also create a no subtree, using the subset of questionnaires that answered no for the question you selected.

Simple Example:

Suppose we're trying to guess the animal, and we have questionnaires from a bear, a zebra, a salmon, and a crocodile.

We look at the questionnaires and see that about half of them said "yes" to "Are you a mammal?", so we'll make that the root of the tree.

Now we take just the questionnaires that said yes to that question.  In our example, they are the ones from the bear and the zebra.  We select the question "Do you have stripes?", since about half of them say yes and half say no.  Since there's only one questionnaire for each of those answers, you create leaf nodes that guess zebra and bear appropriately.

Now we backtrack to the root node and repeat the process for the "no" branch.  That is, we look at the questionnaires for the salmon and the crocodile and select a question that distinguishes that set into separate groups.  "Do you like to smile?" fits the bill.

The final tree looks like this:

```
Ask: "Are you a mammal?"
 |
 +- yes -> Ask: "Do you have stripes?"
 |          |
 |          +- yes -> Guess: Zebra
 |          |
 |          +- no --> Guess: Bear
 |
 +- no --> Ask: "Do you like to smile?"
            |
            +- yes -> Guess: Crocodile
            |
            +- no --> Guess: Salmon
```

Comment: Does this work when the answers are not yes/no ? Because the answers are for all intents and purposes random strings, not yes/no.

Comment: @sjobe: That will work with a slight bit of extra work.  Suppose you have it narrowed down to `x` companies.  A question will split that into a set of other companies.  Let's suppose it splits it into 6, 3, 3, 2, 1 different groups of companies.  Then assign the weight of this question as `6*log(6) + 6*log(3) + 2*log(2) + 1*log(0)`.  Take the question with lowest weight as your next question.

Comment: This gives a greedy algorithm that is trying to choose the next question which will likely result in the smallest average number of future questions until you have your final answer.  If no question can split the group, then you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Building an [Expert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system) using [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) is one possible solution. Have you considered this option ?

By doing so, you may even add some [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) capabilities easing interaction with users.